How to remove whitespace with special character

I have a special character, how to remove special character below
$city_name = "  Hải Phòng";
$city_name = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $city_name));

Result still whitespace


&nbsp; is a non-breaking space, not a whitespace. Consider doing a str_replace

Your image $city_name = "NBSP Hải Phòng", but your code snippets $city_name = "  Hải Phòng". what code do you use?

Just add the u modifier and the NBSP character will be considered as whitespace: '/\s+/u' (see here).

@Olivier are you sure about this? demo

@DarkBee The OP has the raw character in the string, not an HTML entity.

Then OP needs to revise the snippet posted because otherwise the original code works as is - demo

Additional Unicode white space character needs to be included in the regex.
Try this and let me know if it works:
$city_name = "  Hải    Phòng   ";
$city_name = trim(preg_replace('/[[:space:]]+/u', ' ', $city_name));


Did you actually read the question? There is no [space]inside the string, but a &nbsp; as illustrated in OP's screenshot

Did you actually try this youself? https://ideone.com/bGehJh - There is no difference (in this use-case) between \s and [:space:]

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
